# Ignoring errors in a Perl END block

Tags: perl, exception

How do I ignore a `die()` that occurs in a Perl `END` block?

As it is now I get

> END failed--call queue aborted

And the error bubbles up the calling script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your end block inside an `eval { .... }` - this should prevent the behaviour you describe.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print("hi there!\n");

END {
    eval{
        print("goodbye\n");
        die("this can't hurt....");
    };

    #detect if an error occurred in the eval
    if ( $@ ){
        print ("an error occurred: $@\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, this does the trick.    Doesn't seem to work for "exit(..)" inside an eval though?

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob You cannot trap `exit` via `eval`.

Answer (score 5):

Place your code inside eval block and if you want to retrieve the error message that die provides you can capture using if condition outside the block.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $val=1;
eval
{
   print "Inside Eval\n";
   if($val == 1)
   {
     die "hello world\n";
   }
   print "End of Eval\n";
};
if ( $@ )
{
         print  "Error message - $@" . "\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 well done for showing how to pick up the error - have added that to my answer too for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

[`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Try%3a%3aTiny) is an excellent wrapper for `eval`, allowing you to explicitly handle run-time exceptions.